# Cannot see my cucumber file type, .feature file not recognized

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, bdd, feature-file

I added some cucumber dependencies to my `pom.xml` file and tried to create `.feature` file from TEST package but when I do that, it says ".feature is not associated with any file type". I went through the file types and there's no type that'd be assosiated with cucumber. Any ideas why? Thanks
[image]

Comment: Do you have "Cucumber" plugin installed/enabled?

Comment: No, I didn't have it. Now it works. I was not aware it has to be installed, I thought it's only dependencies... 
Thank you!